# Linq segmenting data by status

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, segment

Hey I'm trying to figure out the most optimal way to grab a segment of data in a list. Based on their type
Imagine I have the following data in a list:

```
public enum StepStatus {
    Skipped,
    NotStarted,
    Completed,
}

public enum StepType 

public class Steps {
    StepStatus Status { get; set; }
    StepType Type { get; set;}
    // Other info
}
```

I have a list of all the steps and their statuses

```
//Data
    1, StepStatus.Skipped, StepType.Notification
    2, StepStatus.Completed, StepType.Notification
    3, StepStatus.NotStarted, StepType.Notification
    4, StepStatus.NotStarted, StepType.Notification
    5, StepStatus.NotStarted, StepType.Approval}
    6, StepStatus.NotStarted, StepType.Notification
```

I want to grab all of the NotStarted, notifications, up to and including the first approval. So I want the to return this segment of the list

```
3, StepStatus.NotStarted, StepType.Notification
4, StepStatus.NotStarted, StepType.Notification
5, StepStatus.NotStarted, StepType.Approval
```

The Simplest way I can think to do this would be.

```
var firstApprovalStep =  steps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == StepStatus.NotStarted && x.Type == StepType.Approval);

if(null == firstApprovalStep)
{
   //If there are no pending approvals left return the pending notfications
   return steps.Reverse().TakeWhile(x => x.Status == StepStatus.NotStarted && x.Type == StepType.Notification);
}

//Find the element in the list with that index and grab all prior.
steps.GetNotStartedNotificationsPrior(firstStep);
```

I'm wondering if there is an easer/ more savy way to grab this segment using linq?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to compile.

Comment: Sorry I was pseudo coding I'll make a proper edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know you are using a `List<T>` we can cheat a little and use the source `IEnumerable` twice without much penalty.

Here is an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakePast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> posFn) => items.Take(items.TakeWhile(i => !posFn(i)).Count()+1);
```

Using this, you can do:

```
return steps.Where(s => s.StepStatus == StepStatus.NotStarted)
            .TakePast(s => s.StepType == StepType.Approval);
```

Of course, that means you could just expand the extension method:

```
return steps.Where(s => s.StepStatus == StepStatus.NotStarted)
            .Take(steps.Where(s => s.StepStatus == StepStatus.NotStarted).TakeWhile(s => s.StepType != StepType.Approval)).Count()+1);
```

I am assuming the only `StepType`s are `Notification` and `Approval` since you didn't define the `enum`.

Here is a generic implementation that enumerates any sequence once:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakePast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> posFn) {
    var ie = items.GetEnumerator();
    while (ie.MoveNext()) {
        yield return ie.Current;
        if (posFn(ie.Current))
            yield break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering if there is a way to reverse the iterator, instead of going through the enumerable twice

Comment: @johnny5 I added the generic one pass implementation, if you are willing to use an extension method.